# Launching SSRS Report causes browser to hang

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have a customer portal with a few reports in it.  When I click a report link on the parent page to view a report, a new window opens (window.open) which contains an ASPX page, containing a reportviewer control.

[image]

The report runs (less than 30 seconds):
[image]

But then something strange occurs.

If I remain on the parent page, 15 minutes later, the browser is unresponsive. I cannot browse to any other pages on the site, I need to close and reopen the browser to continue.  If I do NOT choose a report, 15 minutes later the browser is fine.

I've used network tools to see what the network calls looks like, and all I get is that a call was initiated.. nothing indicating a hung HTTP call, etc.  It just.. stops..  If i browse the site immediately after running the report, it's fine!  But if I hang out on the parent page after running the report (even after closing the child report window) I get the unresponsiveness.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code that launches the report.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limited set of compatible browsers, especially on older versions of SQL Server SSRS.  I would always recommend IE, which it looks like you are not using?

Here's the compatibility info (for SQL 2016, there's a version selector at the top of the page):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511.aspx#bkmk_reportviewer

Answer (score 0):

Not really the solution, but finally found a more permanent fix for this.  I developed a separate website that hosts my ReportViewerControl.  I then developed a web form that loads with a meta refresh, after 3 seconds the page will "refresh" and redirect to my secondary ReportViewerControl website.

Something "goofy" was happening here, the session was getting locked up, almost like the more complex the report, the longer the session was locked up, the more of a chance the browser hanging.  Something with the meta refresh and the secondary website causes the session to be completely disconnected (I think???)

There's probably no other person in the world that will have this issue, but if it does, at least others know my story =]