# How do I trace to where my application is locking up

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a hosted Windows Azure website.  I've found a scenario where the website locks up in the users web browser (I asked this question a few months ago - [Launching SSRS Report causes browser to hang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096465/launching-ssrs-report-causes-browser-to-hang)).

I've setup streaming logging and now can view the stream within VS2015.  Im my global.asax, I added a trace statement to the beginning and end of every handler.  On my failed (hanging) requests - see linked post for more details - I see the "PostMapRequestHandler" event fire completely.  The next event that seems to fire (based on monitoring successful requests) is AcquireRequestState.

In my failed request state, I never see AcquireRequestState complete.  If I put in a purposeful error - Throw New Exception("Throw me") - the app will yellow screen.  However if I have just my trace statements here, I never see this method complete.

When I get in this bad state, the browser never gets a response back from the server.  The page will 500 after roughly 5-10 minutes of waiting.  I can only get around this if I close my browser completely and open a new window, essentially tossing out the old session information.

1. Where else can I dig to find out why this is failing in this global method handler?
2. What does it tell me that AcquireRequestState doesn't complete? My gut tells me I'm dealing with some "bad" session mojo here, but am kind of stumped..

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities:

1. Depending on how you're running the site, you may be able to put the .PDB file with the other code onto the server and capture a snapshot of the process as the issue is occurring (you'll need desktop access to the server, which depends on what azure system you're using to host the site).  In the task manager, right-click on the appropriate w3wp process and choose "Create Dump File".
2. It's been deprecated, but in the past, I've had fair (not great) results using `Thread.Suspend()`, `new StackTrace(thread, true)`, and `Thread.Resume()`.  Note that some of these functions have been deprecated, and this needs to be done very carefully. You need to *very carefully* make a list of the Threads as each request comes in, and add a new type of request that walks through the list getting the thread state and dumping it out. (The lack of this functionality in .NET is a serious problem for diagnosing issues such as yours (which are not uncommon in larger systems).
3. Put extra temporary logging code all through the execution path that is causing the issues, recreate the problem, and iteratively examine the log results, and add more logging until you track down the problem.

It sounds suspiciously like an infinite loop to me.

Comment: Thanks so much @James, and totally agree re: infinite loopage.  I'm just hoping to find where the loop is occuring so I can correct my code.  I'll take a whirl with your suggestions, stay tuned!

Comment: Oh, and unfortunately option 1 wont help, since it's a hosted azure website, I dont have access to the direct VM =\

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried attaching the debugger to your web app? You can do so as follows:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/

Having the debugger attached will allow you to see all of the threads, and call stacks, so it should help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks @theadriangreen, I have remote debugged but it doesnt help.  I see the breakpoint hit my trace statement in AcquireRequestState, once it leaves that event handler, nothing else happens.  Im hoping to trace it through to see where it's going to next and where it's dying, but that's as far as I can get before debugging and tracing just stops indicating whats wrong